# blend or flex sensors

Tags: arduino, sensor, wearable

i have to build a kind of dress that can unserstand the blend angles of neck, shoulder, elbow, wrist. i thought the best is to use arduino lillypad and some flex sensors.

i've saw this: http://sensorwiki.org/doku.php/sensors/flexion

but i'm still confused on what kind of sensors could fit best in my project.

for example the sensor in the neck sould be a little more accurate that the one in the shoulder and i don't know if i need a different sensor or i can use different offset via software. then i heard that some flex sensors are going to get broken if they are misuring more than 90° (but.. is it true?) and in my project elbow is blended kind of everytime more than 90°.

can someone give me some advice?

Comment: What accuarcy do you need?

Comment: i don't know exactly how to misure it: i need a value between 0 and 256 when the muscle is completly blended.. for sure i don't need a hight accuracy like medical robotics or similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is the conductive ink kind of sensor.

[image: Flex sensor]

These are a little bit pricey but easy to get hold of. [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8606) have them for $13.

They're pretty easy to use as they act just like a variable resistor, whose resistance changes as you bend it. You can make them into an analogue sensor by adding a fixed resistor. The impedance buffer (an op-amp) is optional, but will result in much better sensor readings, especially as you intend to use fairly long wires to connect the sensor to the Arduino.

[image: Flex sensor circuit]

The [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/FLEXSENSOR%28REVA1%29.pdf) for the sensor (which you should read) contains lots more suggestions for circuits.

You can stitch a little pocket into clothing and insert the flex sensor. Use them in the fingers of a glove:

[image: Flex sensor in glove finger]

Or in a whole dress:

[image: Flex sensor dress]

---

### Added

Accuracy: Flex sensors aren't super accurate sensors. They give you a reasonable sense of an amount of bend, but aren't great for precision applications, E.G. robotic teleoperation. I don't know how much accuracy you need for the neck, so it's very hard for me to say whether it's good enough for you. If you want a more accurate sensor, you'll need to specify exactly how accurate.

Robustness: What will kill the sensor is not the angle of the bend, but the minimum bend radius.

[image: Minimum bend radius]

The [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/FLEXSENSOR%28REVA1%29.pdf) for the ones at Sparkfun didn't mention a minimum bend radius, but [these ones](http://infusionsystems.com/catalog/product_info.php/products_id/54) specify 5mm. I.E. you can bend one around a 10mm diameter tube, and they'll be fine. So I would imagine that going round the outside of an elbow would be OK, but the inside would probably pinch the sensor and break it.

Comment: thanks for fast replay! i've edited a little bit the question

Comment: @nkint - OK, I'll add some more about this.

Comment: ok perfect thanks. last thing: what length? i've seen there are from 1" to 5".. from the length it depends the accuracy, right? more length, more sensibility?

Comment: @nkint - I don't think that the accuracy is affected much by the length. Use whatever length is appropriate for the job. Try it out with a piece of paper cut to length. For the elbow, you'll probably need a long one to make sure you're covering the whole outside of the joint.